# Why stored procedure cannot be used with select, where & having

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Why stored procedure cannot be used with `Select`, `Where` & `Having`?

I understand a function can serve the purpose - what's the reason why a stored procedure cannot be executed in select?

Blogs are answering you can use UDF. Understand we can use UDF & we are using. 
Need a valid reason on stored procedure.

Comment: You Should Not Capitalize Each And Every Word In English ....

Comment: Ok sir, will keep in mind

Comment: this is the syntax and sql specification. IMO, your question is not valid

Comment: It's a logical restriction, really. SQL is a declarative language, whereas stored procedures are (obviously) procedural. If you wanted to call a stored procedure in a `select` statement, where should it go? when should it be executed? Once per output row? Once per statement? There's nothing in the SQL specification that defines this. It's not required anyway because most databases instead put a procedural "layer" on top of SQL - e.g. in oracle you have PL/SQL which is a procedural extension *on top of* SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Biggest reasons most likely is that procedures can return any number of result sets and change data. It can have no results, or it can be 100 different results sets with 0 to n rows. It can also depend on your input parameters. Stored procedure can also affect the underlying data, so what would happen if you would use a stored procedure that changes data in the same table you're using it in the where clause? The results sets don't even necessary have names for the columns, so you couldn't refer them in any way.

So, since for procedures would be really complex to implement anything like that, why should it be possible to use them in where etc? You haven't provided any valid reason why they should.

The reason functions exist, is that you can use them for where clauses etc.